# How can I apply multiple rules in GeoServer CSS while avoiding the generation of multiple legends?

Tags: geoserver, legend, cartography, css

I'm using GeoServer with CSS to style map features. I've defined multiple rules based on the 'street_wid' attribute and a label rule. However, applying these rules results in multiple legends. I want to apply the rules while ensuring that only one legend is displayed.

Here is my current CSS:

````
```css
/* @title < 10 ft */
[street_wid < 10] {
    stroke: #a2b9e0;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
/* @title 11 - 20 ft */
[street_wid > 10][street_wid < 20] {
    stroke: #19b0db;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
/* @title 20 - 30 ft */
[street_wid > 20][street_wid < 30] {
    stroke: #6d3ea3;
    stroke-width: 4px;
}
/* @title > 30 ft */
[street_wid > 30] {
    stroke: #0C1444;
    stroke-width: 4px;
}
/* @scale < 8000 */
[@scale < 8000] {
    label: [street_cod];
    label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
    font-fill: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    label-follow-line: true;
    halo-color: #FFFFFF;
    halo-radius: 2;
}
````

How can I achieve my styling goals while avoiding multiple legends?

[image]